# Does CakeRequest::input() stream data directly from the net?

Tags: cakephp, file-upload, streaming

Just this, I'd like to stream uploaded filed directly from the net to the filesystem to avoid out of memory errors. Can I do it with CakeRequest::input()? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's best to read the API documentation [CakeRequest::input()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-class-CakeRequest.html#809-837) or the source;

http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-class-CakeRequest.html#876

According to the source, 'input()' reads directly from `php://input` via the `_readInput()` method:

However, if I read that part of the source code correctly, it will read the entire stream in memory before returning its content. So I don't think this will give you what you want.

There may be other solutions, maybe a plugin exists. However, you may write your own implementation, using the CakeRequest as an example?

You may also check the [HttpSocket](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/httpsocket.html) class

Comment: Do you know how PHP itself actually handles files upload? Does it read all the file in memory before write it on the tmp folder? Hope not :)